# Adapt a jsfiddle to a working webpage knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, jsfiddle

What I'm ultimately trying to do is get a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Phehb/24/) to work on my desktop, and not in the jsfiddle browser.

I've...

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="[urls from the resource frame of the jsfiddle"></script>
        </head>
    <body>

    ***[content from the jsfiddle HTML pane]***

    </body>
        <script>
           ***[content from the Javascript pane]***
        </script>
</html>
```

however, when I open that doc in Chrome, it contains a list of all items that are formatted in a plain manner, and not in the groovy collpsible objects in the jsfiddle.

I've tried various browsers, ensuring the CDN links aren't rotten.

I've also tried hard refreshing the webpage and under F12\network - it seems to load the `*min.js` files a second time, but as 0 byte files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the

```
    <script>
       ***[content from the Javascript pane]***
    </script>
```

into the body tags and got it working...happy days!

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

I suspect the `rel="stylesheet"` attribute inside the link to the css.

Try including the scripts like so -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```